# With React, how to call a module with a variable in the name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working to load SVG icons dynamically using this React component. Why isn't `<MyIcon.icons[{name}] />` working?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {
  IconHome,
  IconCow,
  IconDog,
} from '../Icon';


const MyIcon = ({
  name,
}) => (
  <div>
    <MyIcon.icons[{name}] />
    {name}
  </div>
);

MyIcon.icons = {
  home: IconHome,
  dog: IconCow,
  cow: IconDog,
};

MyIcon.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default MyIcon;
```

I'm getting the following errror:

`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:22)`

Comment: There's [an answer](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) to this in the docs as well. Adding for somebody's future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to assign the component you want to include to a variable, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {
  IconHome,
  IconCow,
  IconDog,
} from '../Icon';

const icons = {
  home: IconHome,
  dog: IconCow,
  cow: IconDog,
};

const MyIcon = ({ name }) => {
  const SelectedIcon = icons[name];
  return (
    <div>
      <SelectedIcon />
      {name}
    </div>
  )
};

MyIcon.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default MyIcon;
```

Comment: @AnApprentice It's the same as your example above – I just omitted the PropTypes for brevity. Apologies!

Comment: thanks this doesn't seem to work though - erroring preview.bundle.js:8906 Warning: The tag <icon> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @AnApprentice D'oh, sorry – that's my bad. Fixed the example code above.

Comment: @AnApprentice Example updated again to include PropTypes. It's pretty straightforward :)